# how to connect USB device in iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mobile

I am working on an iOS application that has to detect whether a USB is connected to the device being used.

So what I would like to know is the following:

1. Is it possible to detect whether a USB(pendrive) has been plugged into the device?
2. If so, how could one detect this programatically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this iOS app communicate over the USB port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124419/how-does-this-ios-app-communicate-over-the-usb-port)